# Spring data mongodb query skip() works not how it should.

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I discovered that skip() in a query using mongoOperations acts funny.

I have this code:

```
if (question.getCategory() == "" && question.getDifficulty() == 0 && question.getNumberOfCorrectAnswers() == 0) 
        return mongoOperations.find(new Query(Criteria.where("question").regex(questionPattern, "i"))
        .limit(getLimit()).skip(getSkip()), Question.class);
```

I use it in my search method. I want to do a pagination. For example limit the results to 10 and skip the first 5.

limit() works just fine, but skip() when it gets the value of 1 displays the 1st document in the collection. limit() is on 0 by default as to not shorten the range.

I checked in mongodb shell and skip(1) is viewing documents starting from the second one.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? I suspect that you don't even access the if clause. `question.getCategory() == ""` is false (identity). Should be `"".equals(question.getCategory())`

Comment: I found the real issue. I use angularJS and by some mysterious way my ng-models collide and from 2 inputs bound by 2 different models the 1st value goes to the second scope, not the first like it should.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `sort` in your query? Without using a specific sort order the `skip` isn't going to return predictable results for your pagination.

Comment: According to the Mongo docs, it might matter to put the skip() before the limit() - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this instead:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("question").regex(questionPattern, "i");
Query query = Query.query(criteria);
query.limit(getLimit());
query.skip(getSkip());
return mongoOperations.find(query, Question.class);
```

Comment: It gave the same effect. I have 6 documents in the collection. When I skip 2 it shows the first 2, not from 3 to 6.